# Unwrapping Nested Array Recursively

Tags: javascript

I am trying to unwrap a nested array recursively within a function, however; I can't think of a way besides creating a new empty array outside of the function to store. Is there a way I could recursively unwrap a nested array while keeping a new empty array inside the function?

```
var test = [1,2,33,[55,88,[23,[211],66,998],2000],4,2002,[111,58,22,[120],15],68];

var newArray =[];

function nestedArray(arr) {


arr = arr.forEach(function(item,index){
  if(Array.isArray(item)){
    return nestedArray(item);
  }else{

    newArray.push(item)
  }
})
return newArray
}

nestedArray(test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return your function from an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) and put `newArray` inside of same.  The "IIFE" creates a "closure" or "scope" within which both `newArray` and the function that builds it can reside:

```js
var test = [1,2,33,[55,88,[23,[211],66,998],2000],4,2002,[111,58,22,[120],15],68];

var nestedArray = (function() {
  var newArray = [];

  return function(arr) {
    arr = arr.forEach(function(item,index){
      if(Array.isArray(item)){
        return nestedArray(item);
      }else{
        newArray.push(item)
      }
    })
    return newArray;  
  }
})();

console.log( nestedArray(test) );
```

Comment: I took the liberty of putting the code in a snippet so it can be run directly here; hope that's OK!

Comment: @MichaelGeary Yeah that's cool I've never mastered that (actually I've never tried), it made my repl redundant, so I removed that

Comment: Glad that was helpful. Snippets are pretty easy, just use the `<>` button at the top of the edit box. Of course repl.it is really nice for other languages besides JavaScript that aren't supported in a snippet.

Comment: It took me a while to follow this. Why the assignment `arr = arr.forEach(...)`? `Array.forEach` returns `undefined`. Why `return nestedArray(item);` instead of just `nestedArray(item);`? We (and `forEach`) only care about the side effect.

Comment: @AuxTaco I just re-arranged the OP's code into an IIFE without analyzing it like you have ;)

Comment: LOL okay makes sense now.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm still relatively new to javascript and coding in general, so I just had a quick follow up question on IIFE's. Because there are no parameters in the IIFE `nestedArray()` , does the parameter get passed down to the function inside the IIFE when I run it recursively? So by running `nestedArray(item)`, is the parameter `item` automatically passed down into the function `function(arr)` inside?

Comment: @NelsonChen Correct, the IIFE returns the function that accepts the parameter -- `return function(arr)` ....

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = [1,2,33,[55,88,[23,[211],66,998],2000],4,2002,[111,58,22,[120],15],68];

function nestedArray(oldArr, newArr) {
  newArr = newArr || []
  oldArr.forEach(function(item,index){
    if(Array.isArray(item)){
      return nestedArray(item, newArr);
    }else{
      newArr.push(item)
    }
  })
  return newArr
}

console.log(nestedArray(test))
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/hewojap/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

You could always `toString()` it which removes all `[]` then split on the commas.

```js
const array = [1,2,33,[55,88,[23,[211],66,998],2000],4,2002,[111,58,22,[120],15],68];
const newArray = array.toString().split(",").map(val => parseInt(val));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Clever approach

Comment: or just `JSON.parse('[' + array + ']')`

Comment: It's funny before I answered this question I confirmed the OP's way worked, and then merely threw it into an IIFE without considering whether there may be other ways to accomplish the OP's end goal, but there are so many other ways!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `Array#reduce` and `Array#concat` with a little recursion to get the job done. basically you iterate over the given array, if the value is an array recursively call the nested array function and concat the result to the accumulator, or just concat the value to the accumulator array.

```js
var test = [1,2,33,[55,88,[23,[211],66,998],2000],4,2002,[111,58,22,[120],15],68];

const nestedArray = arr =>
  arr.reduce((acc, x) =>
    acc.concat(
      Array.isArray(x)
        ? nestedArray(x)
        : x
    )
  , [])

console.log(
  nestedArray(test)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way without using an IIFE

```
var test = [1,2,33,[55,88,[23,[211],66,998],2000],4,2002,[111,58,22,[120],15],68];

var nestedArray = function(arr) {
  var newArray = [];


  arr.forEach(function(item,index){
      if(Array.isArray(item)){
        var storage = nestedArray(item);
        newArray = newArray.concat(storage)
      }else{
        newArray.push(item)
      }
    })

  return newArray;  
}


nestedArray(test);
```

by creating `var storage`, it allows me to store the results of what is recursed and I can concat the results of my new array to my old array.